# Java 8 check the class or instance of an object that extends another object

Tags: class, for-loop, java-8

First, please don't shoot me for my words. I'm a french new dev with a little English level.

I'm trying to control the class of an object that extend another object :

**Context :**

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B
class D extends A
class E extends A 

List<A> cbdeList = new ArrayList<A>()
cbdeList .add(new C())
cbdeList .add(new B())
cbdeList .add(new D())
cbdeList .add(new E())

List<T> tList

for (A item : cbdeList ) { /* code that do something with tList */ }
```

**Need :**

Stop the loop if the class of  item is B and only B.

**tryouts done :**

item instanceOf B

- returns true even if `item.getClass() == C`.
- I think because a `C` class object inherits `B` class.

item.getClass().isInstance(B)

- return false on a `B` class item.
- I don't understand why.

I have thinked that I had the good way with :

- `item.getClass().isAssignableFrom(B.class)`

**or**

- `item.getClass().equals(B.class)`

But I read somewhere "on the Internets" (but don't remember where) that work with `item.getClass()` and `B.class` was not the best practice.

For now, I have modified the loop (forit > fori) :

```
for (i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++ )
{ 
    /* code */ 
    if(!(i == 1 && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(tList))) 
    { loop output } 
    /* code */
 }
```

but that implies being sure of the order of the list items.

**Questions :**

- a better way to control the class ?
- a more efficient loop output than a "`break`" or a "`continue`" ?
- Is the insert order in an ArrayList() always respected in a loop ?

Comment: `if(item.getClass() == B.class) …`, regarding “not best practice”, that applies to what you are trying to do, so it doesn’t matter which way you do it, as every way to achieve that, will be marked as “not best practice”, simply for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question:

```
for (A item : cbdeList) { 
    if (item.getClass() == B.class) {
        break; // Stop the loop
    }
    // ...do some stuff...
}
```

To your second question: `break` and `continue` have completely different meaning. One breaks the loop, the other just skips the current step.

And to your third question: `List` implementations represent ordered collections and `add` method is adding items to the end of the list.